# aws cli ec2 describe commands return nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to get the json output of a nacl that I setup in the console with the following command:

> aws ec2 --profile my-profile --region us-east-1 describe-network-acls

The command appears to execute fine but there is never returned output. It's just blank with (END). I validated the nacl is setup under vpc and it is associated with two subnets.

I have even tried multiple other commands like describe-subnet or even describe-instance and I get the same output. I can run `aws iam get-user` and it returns my user profile fine.

Looking at my user permissions and I have full permissions into EC2.

Im at a loss, any ideas?

aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.45 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.6.0 exe/x86_64

OS: MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2 (20G95)

EDIT (requested config and terminal used)
terminal: iterm/zsh

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

Comment: I notice that your AWS CLI is not using a recent version. Just in case it helps, you might want to update your AWS CLI installation.

Comment: Can you show the aws config stored in your ~/.aws/config file and more specifically, whether do you have an output field set to something (e.g. text, json, etc). In addition which terminal and shell do you use, and do you have any additional frameworks on top?

Comment: @Nick updated post with requested info. I have tried both setting output in config and manually in the command along with none set and it does not make a difference. Ill try updating CLI version when I can.

Comment: uninstall/reinstall along with --no-verify-ssl solved the problem. See my comment below

Comment: Did you get chance to look at cloudwatch --> logs? There should be an entry here matching your request with reason for failure. If there is none, high possibility the request didn't reach your account itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fully uninstalled the AWS CLI from my Mac, then reinstalled. From there, running the commands gave an SSL error which it never gave before:

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)

Tested with `-no-verify-ssl`, and all works now.

Answer (score 1):

Add `DescribeNetworkAcls` under VPC access. You can add custom policy which allow `DescribeNetworkAcls`.

Below is list policy allow under VPC or EC2 :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:AcceptVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:AssignIpv6Addresses",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:AssociateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:AssociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:AssociateVpcCidrBlock",
                "ec2:AttachClassicLinkVpc",
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateCarrierGateway",
                "ec2:CreateCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:CreateDefaultSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateDefaultVpc",
                "ec2:CreateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:CreateEgressOnlyInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateFlowLogs",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateLocalGatewayRouteTableVpcAssociation",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:CreateRoute",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointConnectionNotification",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
                "ec2:CreateVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:CreateVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteCarrierGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DeleteEgressOnlyInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteFlowLogs",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteLocalGatewayRouteTableVpcAssociation",
                "ec2:DeleteNatGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointConnectionNotifications",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeCarrierGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeClassicLinkInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeCustomerGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeEgressOnlyInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeFlowLogs",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeIpv6Pools",
                "ec2:DescribeLocalGatewayRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeLocalGatewayRouteTableVpcAssociations",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeMovingAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeNatGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfacePermissions",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupReferences",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupRules",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeStaleSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointConnectionNotifications",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServicePermissions",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpnConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpnGateways",
                "ec2:DetachClassicLinkVpc",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DisableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:DisableVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:DisableVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
                "ec2:DisassociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DisassociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:DisassociateVpcCidrBlock",
                "ec2:EnableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:EnableVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:EnableVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules",
                "ec2:ModifySubnetAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointConnectionNotification",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServicePermissions",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcPeeringConnectionOptions",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcTenancy",
                "ec2:MoveAddressToVpc",
                "ec2:RejectVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:RejectVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclAssociation",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:ReplaceRoute",
                "ec2:ReplaceRouteTableAssociation",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:RestoreAddressToClassic",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:UnassignIpv6Addresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My account does have a policy (EC2, AmazonEC2FullAccess) with these permissions set. I have also verified I get a returned error when I dont have permissions for a resource.

Comment: Above mentioned list not from EC2. its from VPC list. You have to give `DescribeNetworkAcls` from VPC list.

Comment: I went ahead and created a new user-group with the AmazonVPCFullAccess role which appears identical to what you pasted above and applied it to my user account. Still the same results

Answer (score 0):

Try reconfiguring it by running `aws configure` in the console. I was having the same problem and that did the trick for me.